# Animation on UITableViewCell shadow not working

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-animation

I wanted to create a shadow animation effect when the user clicks on the cell, where the cell will have a shadow "growing" from 0 to the intended radius.

Below are the snapshots of the codes but I can't get it to animate:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [CATransaction begin]; {
        [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:5];
        cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
        cell.layer.shadowRadius = 20;
        cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
    }
    [CATransaction commit];

    [tableView_ deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CABasicAnimation  *animShadow = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowRadius"];
    animShadow.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    animShadow.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:20];
    animShadow.duration = 3.0;
    [cell.layer addAnimation:animShadow forKey:@"shadowRadius"];

    [tableView_ deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `CABasicAnimation` animation instead, for example,
to animate only, `shadowOpacity` u can try below code

```
 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    //animation  shadowOpacity
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowOpacity"];
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    animation.duration = 1.0f;

    [cell.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shadowOpacityAnimation"];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 20.0f;
 }
```

to animate both `shadowOpacity` and `shadowRadius` u can use below code

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //animation both the shadowOpacity and shadowRadius
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowOpacity"];
   animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
   animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];

   CABasicAnimation *shadowRadiusAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowRadius" ];
   shadowRadiusAnimation.fromValue =[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
   shadowRadiusAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:20.0];

   CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
   group.animations = @[animation,shadowRadiusAnimation];
   group.duration = 1.0f;

   [cell.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"shadowGroupAnimation"];
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
   cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
   cell.layer.shadowRadius = 20.0f;
}
```

to animate only `shadowRadius` u can use below code

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //animation  shadowRadius
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


  CABasicAnimation *shadowRadiusAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowRadius" ];
  shadowRadiusAnimation.fromValue =[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
  shadowRadiusAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:20.0];
shadowRadiusAnimation.duration = 1.0f;

  [cell.layer addAnimation:shadowRadiusAnimation forKey:@"shadowRadiusAnimation"];
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
  cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f; //set final values
  cell.layer.shadowRadius = 20.0f;
}
```

the effect is quite similar not too different,

**Edit**
Pushing the view controller after finish the animation
For this u can set the animation delegate and it is called after the animation finished.

for example,

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //animation both the shadowOpacity and shadowRadius
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowOpacity"];
   animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
   animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];

   CABasicAnimation *shadowRadiusAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowRadius" ];
   shadowRadiusAnimation.fromValue =[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
   shadowRadiusAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:20.0];

   CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
   group.delegate = self; //this line set the delegate to self,
   //if u use other option's also u can set the delegate for 
   //"CABasicAnimation" also just set it to self and implement the
   // delegate method
   group.animations = @[animation,shadowRadiusAnimation];
   group.duration = 1.0f;
   [cell.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"shadowGroupAnimation"];
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
   cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
   cell.layer.shadowRadius = 20.0f; 
}


//implement the delegate method this is called when animation stops with the flag,

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag
 {
   if(flag)
   {
     SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your codes works. I also found my issue, because right after the codes above, I have a navigationController transition animation; and by adding those, the shadow animation would not appear when the UITableViewCell is selected. Can you advice what I should do so that I can animate the shadow and then followed by the navigationController transition animation?

Comment: When I added this into the last line:     [self.navigationController pushViewController:_newViewController animated:YES]; then, i no longer able to see the shadow animation and the screen will directly transition to the next ViewController.

Comment: okay u want to push the view controller after the shadow animation completes ..?

Comment: hello. how to remove Groupanimation when animation end